# Float displaying in format that uses comma, but jquery wants a format with dot

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My server converts float into a string using comma and then jquery alerts, that this float's format is incorrect (it requires dot). I'm not familiar with this auto generated jquery validation script and I don't know where to change it, so I'm asking here.

Here's my code and a pic of alert.

```
    @model NerdDinner.Models.Dinner

    (...)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitude)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Longitude)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitude)
    </div>
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking -- do you want to change the (jQuery) client or the ASP.NET server? (and please retag your question based on which!)

Comment: well, it would be cool to know both of these

Comment: There's no way we can help you fix either unless we can see the code for them.

Comment: There is only an object created by LINQ (Dinner - auto generated class) and it's float properties (Latitude, Longitude). I didn't even ask visual studio to add validation for me, it did it on it's own. I wasn't implementing any validation myself.

Comment: I think, you are looking for one of the answers here (might not want to modify it globally though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086494/asp-net-mvc-set-number-format-default-decimal-thousands-separators

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can take those values ​​and convert into float doing a replace of "," by ".":

```
var Longitude = parseFloat($("#longitude").val().replace(",", "."));
var Latitude= parseFloat($("#latitude").val().replace(",", "."));
```

Answer (score 0):

As Steven De Waele has mentioned in his post at [Validating numbers with comma’s with jQuery](http://www.stevendewaele.be/?p=183), you can override the methods of the jQuery validation plugin to achieve your goal.

```
$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
return this.optional(element) || 
                 (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <=  param[1]);
} 

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
return this.optional(element) ||
              /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
```